# How to check if a key has been stored before or not in app-localstorage-document?

Tags: javascript, polymer, local-storage, web-component, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a key is empty in the [app-localstorage-document](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-storage/elements/app-localstorage-document) or not. Earlier I used [iron-localstorage](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-localstorage/elements/iron-localstorage) in which there was an event `on-iron-localstorage-load-empty`, which was invoked when key is empty.

I used the following code for `iron-localstorage`:

```
<iron-localstorage name="my-app-storage" value="{{cat}}" on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="initializeDefaultCat" on-iron-localstorage-load="loadCatFromLocal"></iron-localstorage>

initializeDefaultCat(){
    //some code to initialize the key
}

loadCatFromLocal(){
   //some code to load the key when webpage opens
   // and manipulate the data as per requirement
}
```

I tried the following using app-localstorage-document:

```
<app-localstorage-document key="CatValue" data="{{cat}}"></app-localstorage-document>

class MyApp extends Polymer.Element{
   static get is(){return 'my-app';}
   static get properties(){
     return{
       cat:{
         type: String,
         value: ""
       }
     };
   }

   zeroValue(){
     this.set('cat',"a cat");
   }
}
```

The `zeroValue()` needs to be invoked from somewhere but, I don't know from where to invoke it. In case of `iron-localstorage` the function was invoked from component tag itself using events,but there's no such event in the `app-localstorage-document`. All I want to do is initialize the key when the key is being stored for the first time or when the key is empty and load the key on page load to manipulate the data according to the app requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static get properties(){
   return{
     cat:{
       type: String,
       value: "a cat"
       observer: "zeroValue",
     }
   };
 }

 zeroValue(newValue){
  if (newValue) { this.set('cat', newValue; } 
  else          { this.set('cat',"a cat"); }
 }
```

I haven't used the element myself. Is `value` returning null if the key in localStorage doesn't exist? If it doesn't, then you don't need the `zeroValue` method, and instead set a default value.

Comment: Well it doesn't work as expected. `zeroValue()` is being called twice at a go. So, not a good implementation.